# Any modified Firefox plugin is auto-deleted upon starting Firefox - How do I stop that?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, plugins

When I rename an .xpi to a .zip, unzip it, delete the original .xpi, re-zip the directory, and rename it to .xpi, Firefox deletes this "touched" file upon restart (nothing really changed, other than the modified date).  I watch it disappear from the folder as Firefox starts.  (If you set the read-only flag Firefox still deletes it.)  I'm following the Mozilla guide - and it says to compress the file with "send to > compressed zip folder" and then rename it to .xpi.

I originally thought I was messing up the file, and Firefox was deleting it because it was broken.  Then I just unzipped and rezipped a working plugin, and Firefox promptly removes it.  It's nice to know (and quite surprising) that Firefox detects these changes - but how do I turn that off?

(I'm changing some .js code in an existing plugin to alter how it works.)

Comment: 1. Delete signature `META-INF/`. 2. Depending on OS, delete `.DS_Store` or `.ini` files

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to following reasons:

1. You zipped the main directory of extension files. You must zip all the sub directories of main directory.
2. The add-on is digitally signed which is indicated by META-INF folder. Modifying content of add-on will invalidate signature. Remove the folder to make extension unsigned.
3. We must zip the folder not 7zip, rar, tar.gz etc...

mostly it would be due to reason 1 since you have mentioned "re-zip the directory" in question.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox may think that the add-on is modified. You can disable signatures by going to about:config and changing the value of xpinstall.signatures.required to false. Keep in mind that this will allow other unsigned add-ons to be installed into Firefox.